# SQL - Select using values from 2 Columns that should be at least once on both

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following information

```
|----------------------| 
|       Table1         |   
|----------------------| 
| Id  | Info1 | Info2  |    
|----------------------|    
| 101 | foo   | bar    |    
| 102 | bar   | fubar  |   
| 103 | tot   | bar    |    
| 104 | fubar | foo    |    
| 105 | foo   | fubar  |    
| 106 | spur  | tot    |     
| 107 | sar   | nat    |
```

I need to create a query in order to only get rows where the data in Info1 is at least once in the column Info2 and the one in Info2 is at least once in Info1, meaning that the rows with "tot", "spur" and "sar" in Info1 shouldn't appear in the results, because "spur" and "sar" are only in Info1 and in the case of "tot" it is on both columns but since the row "spur" shouldn't appear then the row with "tot" in Info1 doesn't meet  the criteria to be shown.

I have try with the following which almost got me what I want

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Table1 a
WHERE   EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    Table1 b
        WHERE   a.Info2 = b.Info1
    ) and 
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    Table1 c
        WHERE   a.Info1 = c.Info2
    )
```

But it returns me:

```
| Id  | Info1 | Info2  |    
|----------------------|    
| 101 | foo   | bar    |    
| 102 | bar   | fubar  |   
| 103 | tot   | bar    |    
| 104 | fubar | foo    |    
| 105 | foo   | fubar  |
```

Am I doing something wrong? or should I look for a different approach?

These are the expected results:

```
| Id  | Info1 | Info2  |    
|----------------------|    
| 101 | foo   | bar    |    
| 102 | bar   | fubar  |   
| 104 | fubar | foo    |    
| 105 | foo   | fubar  |
```

Comment: For start dont know why you use `GROUP BY` have you try to remove it?

Comment: My mistake I just copy-paste the last try I did. Already try without it and actually it makes no difference, I'll remove from the post.

Comment: Just to be clear your query already handle `spur` and `sar` right now the problem is `tot`

Comment: Yes, plus I don't want to have a very complex query since this is going to be use a lot for a large amount of information.

Comment: You should include your desire output.. Right now you only show the "wrong" output

Comment: I added the expected results to the post.

Comment: There is no simple way of doing this query.  Your attempt is the best you can do in one go;  you would then have to apply the same logic to the resulting set, or alternatively have it nested inside.

Comment: @AdamMartin OP query isnt working. So still need a working solution first.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza OP query is working in that everything it returns has a matching pair.  He just needs to then do the same thing to the resulting table, removing the line with id=103.  The question is how many passes he wants to have, since I could build a theoretical n-size input that would require n passes.

Comment: @AdamMartin Please can you try to test my solution with a 4-5-pass input?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `with table1 as (select 1 as id, 'tar' as Info1, 'foo' as Info2 union all
                  select 2 as id, 'foo' as Info1, 'bar' as Info2 union all
                  select 3 as id, 'bar' as Info1, 'car' as Info2 union all
                  select 4 as id, 'car' as Info1, 'fish' as Info2)` Breaks your code

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38f5a/4)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM table1 a
inner join table1 b
   on (   a.Info1 = b.Info2
       or a.Info2 = a.Info1
      )
inner join table1 c
   on (   b.Info2 = c.Info1
       or b.Info1 = c.Info2
      )
  and a.Id <> c.Id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|  Id | Info1 | Info2 |
|-----|-------|-------|
| 101 |   foo |   bar |
| 102 |   bar | fubar |
| 104 | fubar |   foo |
| 105 |   foo | fubar |
```

**Big Warning**

If more than 3 steps are need it may break my code

```
CREATE TABLE table2
    ([Id] int, [Info1] varchar(5), [Info2] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO table2
    ([Id], [Info1], [Info2])
VALUES
    (101, 'tar', 'foo'),
    (102, 'foo', 'bar'),
    (103, 'bar', 'car'),
    (104, 'car', 'fish');
```

Comment: @AdamMartin Looks like is sqlfiddle having some issue now

Comment: Your solution works for what I was looking but Adam's solution also works so I will test efficiency and large amount of data before actually marking the answer

Comment: Ohh yes, I saw your data break my code already. thinking about it. But looks like a recursive CTE will be need it

Comment: @RobertoSevilla as Adam mention both our answer will break if a more than 3 pass is need it. As I include in my answer. Let me know if that could happen or not

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Info1 in (SELECT Info2 FROM Table1)
  AND Info2 in (SELECT Info1 FROM Table1)
  AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Table1
                 WHERE (Info1 in (SELECT Info2 FROM Table1)
                        AND Info2 not in (SELECT Info1 FROM Table1))
                    OR (Info2 in (SELECT Info1 FROM Table1)
                        AND Info1 not in (SELECT Info2 FROM Table1))
                )
```

It got a bit messy with all the nested selects, but that should work.

Comment: But the OP's question states "where the data in Info1 is at least once in the column Info2 AND the one in Info2 is at least once in Info1"

Comment: Yeah Joe's query is equivalent to the OP's query, the problem with both of them is the case OP is considering right now.  For that case you need to use a CTE

Comment: Oh, I kind of skipped over the extra clause in his question there. I can modify this though, just a sec...

Comment: You could try using the sqlFiddle in my answer. And check OP desire output in latest edit.

Comment: Thanks Juan, playing with it now :)

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt #1**

```
select t.*
from
    T as t
    inner join (
        select distinct Info1 as value from T t1 inner join T t2 on t2.Info2 = t1.Info1
    ) as v
        on v.value in (Info1, Info2)
```

**Attempt #2**

Seeing the requirement that **both** columns must also appear in the other list, I offer this suggestion. The first query solves a different problem.

```
select t.Id, t.Info1, t.Info2
from
    T as t
    inner join T as t2
        on t2.Info2 = t.Info1 and t2.Id <> t.Id
    inner join T as t3
        on t3.Info1 = t.Info2 and t3.Id <> t.Id
group by t.Id, t.Info1, t.Info2
```

I see that this still doesn't remove row 103 so I've realized that the requirement was still a little more complicated. I'll come back to this later...

**Attempt #3**

...Not sure [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb5dc/13) is elegant but it does work:

```
with
pass1(Info) as (
    select distinct t1.Info1 from T t1 inner join T t2 on t2.Info2 = t1.Info1
),
pass2(Info) as (
    select distinct case n when 1 then Info1 when 2 then Info2 end
    from T, (select 1 union all select 2) as split(n)
    where  Info1 not in (select Info from pass1)
        or Info2 not in (select Info from pass1)
)
select * from T
where   Info1 not in (select Info from pass2)
    and Info2 not in (select Info from pass2)
```

I use **T** as stand-ins for your tables true name. In my view "Table1" makes the queries look more complicated.

Comment: I dont think this give you the right answer. Check this [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38f5a/5)

Comment: Yeah, I guess there was an extra requirement buried in there.

Comment: OP add the desire output. I still wondering if your touple comparasion will improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

it's not difficult you just need a `self join` and an `exists` clause:

```
select distinct t.*
from table1 t
join table1 t1 on t.info1=t1.info2
where exists(
  select * from table1 t2
  where t2.info2=t1.info1
)
```

[here is the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38f5a/10)

Comment: I suggest deleting this answer because it does not give the requested output for the requested input (did not downvote btw)

Comment: @AdamMartin please never mind I apologize if your answer became unaccepted or not, I just want to SO be a better and more valid place and helper for all of us

Comment: I'm not upset lol, just saying your answer is wrong, so I suggest deleting it.  Juan has a valid answer that contains the information I was trying to get accross.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it again, can you say by example why not gives correct answer?

Comment: @Tan_Blaytan  Look like downvote was removed, I  think this solve the OP case. But the three steps case will also break yours

Comment: The fiddle just need distinct ;)

Comment: Ow thank you very much for noticing the problem I missed the distinct keyword (I hurried while copying the fiddle link) corrected.